Spark SQL In Databricks
I am facing issue on the Sparksql Query I have developed One fact In Databricks I am trying to execute The Fact its taking longer Time I want to know which particular part taking so much time. What are steps I need to do For finding the Piece of code??
df1 = sql("""

select LastUpdatedDate from Database.TablesLog where TableName = 'Table1'
""")
if not df1.head(1):
    spark.sql("""insert into Database.TablesLog(TableName, LastUpdatedDate,Type) values ('Table1','
1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000','GGGG')
    """)

I have split the code and executed it but its asking the previous logic.

Sorry but this question is almost unintelligible and there is no way to diagnose the problem without knowing anything about the table.

Please try to explain your problem is simple terms, it's pretty difficult to know what you tried to say.

I have Developed One Fact In Databricks Iam trying to exicute the Fact Its taking 6 hours Time I need to reduse The Exicution time And I want to know Which PArt of Code Taking longer Time.

@Radhaa - your comment is basically saying the same thing as your question. Please edit to be very specific. Right now, the only way anyone would know why something is taking 6 hours... is to run your query against the exact same dataset, in the exact same environment you've set up (so, that would need to be you).
